# Белый экран в onCreate

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.В `onCreate()` делаю некоторые несложные действия.При запуске приложения сначала идет белый экран на 5 сек где то, а потом уже показывается дизайн. Почему такое происходит и как это исправить?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.header1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header1);
    this.header2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header2);
    this.header3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header3);
    this.header4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header4);
    this.header5 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header5);
    this.header6 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header6);
    this.header7 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header7);
    this.header8 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header8);
    this.header9 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header9);
    this.header10 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header10);
    this.header11 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header11);
    this.header12 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header12);
    this.header13 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header13);
    this.header14 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header14);
    this.header15 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header15);
    this.header16 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header16);
    this.header17 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header17);
    this.header18 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header18);
    this.header19 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header19);
    this.header20 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header20);
}
```

Comment: Покажите свой `onCreate()`

Comment: В onCreate нахожу элемент по id из xml.Их штук 20

Comment: Подождите, разметка устанавливается в setContentView(). Это до того, как надо искать элементы по id. Покажите код.

Comment: Код плиз - не ленитесь :)

Comment: this.header = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header); и таких 20 шт

Comment: Добавьте код функции onCreate() в тело вопроса.

Comment: Смотрите выложил

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос. Вы не приняли ни одного ответа на ваши вопросы, это принципиальная позиция?

Comment: В смысле?Я принимал

Comment: @pavlofff в 1 из 20 вопросов ответ таки принят.

Answer (score 5):

Инфлейт разметки происходит методом `setContentView()` - именно он читает XML-файл и на его основе строит изображение на экране. То есть, результатом выполнения этого метода является изображение, следовательно действия после этого метода на скорость отображения никак не влияют.

Учитывая, сколько у вас в последствии ищется только контейнеров (а они наверняка содержат еще большое количество виджетов в себе) не трудно предположить, что инфлейт такой разметки занимает достаточное количество времени.

Вам необходимо оптимизировать свою xml-разметку, сделать ее более простой и линейной. Для начала ее необходимо "прогнать" через [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/hierachyviewer.php) (в настоящее время это не отдельный файл, а  [входит в инструменты](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) Android Studio), чтобы определить проблемные места, затем думать, как решить эти проблемы. Все "лампочки" всех элементов разметки в идеале должны быть зелеными, на крайний случай - желтыми. Универсальных решений тут нет, но есть общие рекомендации [по оптимизации разметки](https://habrahabr.ru/post/279979/), и [еще](http://src-code.net/ispolzovanie-razmetki/) и вот [еще](http://androzp.blogspot.ru/2012/02/android-training_4906.html).

Comment: Ок попробую.к сожалению из разметки не выкинуть ничего уже т.к. все я оптимизировал.

Comment: @Ivan мне, например, трудно представить разметку, в которой действительно нужны 20 контейнеров

Answer (score 0):

В общем даже при разметке с одним RelativeLayout получал белый экран на 2-3 секунды.Решение было найдено очень простое.

В **colors.xml** добавить цвет фона

```
<color name="background">#000000</color>
```

В **styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
```

Странно почему никто про это не знал.

Comment: Изменение цвета бэкграунда не ускорит появление виджетов, если вам нужно было убрать именно белый цвет, то об этом и надо было писать в вопросе.

Comment: @ pavlofff вопрос и стоял как убрать белый экран.Что разметка с одним RelativeLayout что моя большая грузится почти одинаково.