# Проблемы с разметкой xml

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы три кнопки были прижаты к левому краю, а четвертая к правому.
Что не так делаю?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        >
            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClBtnMunu"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
            />
            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCrtNew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClCreateNewCard"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_low_black_24dp"
            />
            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCrt2Card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClCrt2Card"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_high_black_24dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOneTwoCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"

            android:onClick="onClCrt2Card"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_high_black_24dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: У вас там горизонтальные LinearLayout друг в друге. Так нельзя делать. Надо чередовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClBtnMunu"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCrtNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClCreateNewCard"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCrt2Card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClCrt2Card"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOneTwoCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:onClick="onClCrt2Card"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Убрал ресурсы, потому кнопки маленькие.

Comment: Я выбрал это вариант. 1.LinearLayout мне больше нравится, 2.ViewFlipper корректно работает, а в примере с RelativeLayout он работать не захотел.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала, почему лишние виджеты\контейнеры в разметке, это плохо и [что из-за этого будет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/638816/177345).

Теперь сама разметка, лишенная лишних элементов (для демонстрации зоны флиппера он окрашен в зеленый):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="onClBtnMunu"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCrtNew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_low_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="onClCreateNewCard" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCrt2Card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnCrtNew"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_high_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="onClCrt2Card" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOneTwoCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_high_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="onClCrt2Card" />

        <ViewFlipper
             android:id="@+id/flipper"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_below="@+id/btnMenu" >
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#00ff00">

                  <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Первый экран" />

         </LinearLayout>
       </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: Спасибо! Ссылочка по оптимизации виджетов тоже полезная!

Comment: Исправил немного, сократил еще на один лэйаут, спасибо @AndreyAlimov, что подсказал.

Comment: У меня ViewFlipper почему то не захотел работать, хотя при отладке ошибок не показывал, но при запуске программы она сразу вылетала даже не показав экран. Использовал вариант от Аксенов Владимир, все заработало. Не понятно почему, принцип тот же.

Comment: @kaаa какая ошибка в logcat? Все эти многоэтажные лэйауты из ответа Владимира - бесполезный расход ресурсов и времени

Comment: Че то я не догадался посмотреть, спешил, сделал другим способом и пошел дальше. Потом еще раз попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: Там еще проблема была в том, что ViewFlipper растягивался на весь экран и на нем оказывались кнопки. А в него грузятся разные разметки при неизменной шапке с кнопками. Может это было причиной.

Comment: @kaaa Я сейчас протестировал эту разметку - все корректно отображается, ничего не растягивается на весь экран и ничего не вылетает. Очевидно у вас проблема в другом месте.

Comment: Попробовал еще раз. Да, растягиваний нет, все норм, но при запуске прога сразу закрывается с ошибкой. Видимо у меня что-то не так, но разбираться сейчас некогда.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае разметка сложная и лучше, на мой взгляд, использовать RelativeLayout. Нужно максимально стараться убирать вложености:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClBtnMunu"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCrtNew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClCreateNewCard"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnMenu"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_low_black_24dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCrt2Card"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClCrt2Card"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnCrtNew"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_high_black_24dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnOneTwoCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="onClCrt2Card"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_high_black_24dp"/>

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnCrt2Card"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: а чем ваш код отличается от моего?

Comment: зачем использовать еще один LinearLayout если все можно вложить в один Relative?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Вообще он для `ViewFlipper` был, я как то с позиционированием кнопок увлекся и про него забыл. С другой стороны у вас его вообще нет. И ваши 3 левых кнопки будут идти вниз, а не вправо и одна с правой строны

Comment: Совершенно верно. Не сильно разбирался с первоначальной разметкой. Думал что три нужно в столбец. И про флипер забыл.